# Can't record sound with node-record-lpcm16 on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, sox, google-speech-api

I'm building app that uses Google-Cloud-API for speech recognition. 
As it's said [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/streaming-recognize?hl=th#performing_streaming_speech_recognition_on_an_audio_stream) it require `node-record-lpcm16` to record speech.
This library require sox to be installed. On mac it works fine, but on windows it runs without errors but stops recording after 1 second. 
I've installed binaries that provides in documentation and added folder path to `PATH` variable.

Initialisation:

```
const recognizeStream = speech.createRecognizeStream(request)
    .on('error', reject)
    .on('data', data => // process data);

  record
    .start({
      sampleRateHertz,
      threshold: 0.1,
      verbose: true,
      recordProgram: 'sox',
      silence: '1.0',
    })
    .on('error', reject)
    .on('end', resolve)
    .pipe(recognizeStream);
```

It was an error like `Error: spawn sox ENOENT`. But it has missed after installing SOX.
I haven't found any advice how to fix or debug it.

Changing `silence` options to other value didn't change anything.

I'll be appreciate to any advice or thoughts how to fix this.
Sorry for my English

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you solved the issue? I  am getting the same error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while back. Look at "freund17 commented on Nov 23, 2016" comment on this link: https://github.com/gillesdemey/node-record-lpcm16/issues/8#issuecomment-332175548

After you add the extra variables to your index.js file in your node_modules > lpcm16 folder, you can add "Microphone" after -d such as

'-d', 'Microphone'

This worked for me. What I actually tried first was trying to record from sox using the sox -d waveaudio file.wav command. It only worked for me when I added Microphone as the device so I went ahead and added it to the index.js file in lpcm16.

Answer (score -2):

Try installing sox with node-record-lpcm16.
Use this command to install sox: npm install sox